# Azure Bacpac: How to compress a bacpac within SSMS

Tags: azure-sql-database, bacpac

Is there a better way/quicker way to export an azure database via SSMS with it being compressed via the Export Data-tier Application? In the Advanced settings, there are only options to select the tables to be exported.

When you take a .bak file, you are able to compress it in `Backup Options`. Is there an option when you do it via .bacpac?

[image]

In the database we are trying to obtain a bacpac for, we have a column of type `varbinary(max)` in one table and that is where it takes a long time to export/data size. The total size is about 3.5 GB when it is all said and done.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SqlPackage.exe /Action:Export` instead; there are more options, for example CompressionOption can be set to Normal, Maximum, Fast, SuperFast, NotCompressed.
The default is Normal, which I believe is what SSMS uses too. Usage and other parameters can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-export

An example command to export from a local SQL server with Maximum compression:

`sqlpackage.exe /Action:Export /SourceServerName:"." /SourceDatabaseName:"Contoso.Database" /TargetFile:"C:\sqlpackageoutput\output_current_version.bacpac" /p:CompressionOption=Maximum`

If you are trying to make the export faster, try SuperFast. If you are aiming for smallest bacpac file then try Maximum.